# Pointers messing with the address of array elements

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

OK, first let me provide 2 programs:

Program 1:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[5], i;
    int *ptr;

    ptr = a;

    cout << "Enter the elements of the array:" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }

    cout << endl;

    cout << "*ptr:";
    for ( i=0 ; i<5 ; i++ )
    {
        cout << *ptr ;
        *ptr++ ;
    }

    cout << "&a[i]:" << endl ;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << &a[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << endl ;

    cout << "ptr:" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << (ptr+i) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> Enter the elements of the array: 1 2 3 4 5
>   *ptr: 12345
>
> &a[i]:
>   0018FF30
>   0018FF34
>   0018FF38
>   0018FF3C
>   0018FF40
>
> ptr:
>   0018FF44
>   0018FF48
>   0018FF4C
>   0018FF50
>   0018FF54

Program 2:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[5], i;
    int *ptr;

    ptr = a;

    cout << "Enter the elements of the array:" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }

    cout << endl;

    cout << "*ptr:" << endl ;
    for ( i=0 ; i<5 ; i++ )
    {
        cout << *(ptr+i) ;
    }

    cout << "&a[i]:" << endl ;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << &a[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << endl ;

    cout << "ptr:" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << (ptr+i) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> Enter the elements of the array: 1 2 3 4 5
>
> *ptr: 12345
>
> &a[i]:
>   0018FF30
>   0018FF34
>   0018FF38
>   0018FF3C
>   0018FF40
>
> ptr:
>   0018FF30
>   0018FF34
>   0018FF38
>   0018FF3C
>   0018FF40

From the above programs, we can see that ***ptr** in both the cases displays the same output.

I know that the code in Program 2 is the correct way of incrementing when dealing with pointers.

BUT, the **ptr** in both the programs are not same. I am pretty sure that the for loop which is used to display ***ptr** in Program 1 is responsible for this mess. I want to know what is happening in the for loop to display ***ptr** in Program 1 because of which **ptr** is affected.

Comment: `*ptr++` will modify the value of `ptr`.

Comment: Just to point it out (no pun intended) the `*` is superflous in the statement `*ptr++`. All the `*` does is dereference the pointer after it was incremented. I.e. It should read `ptr++`.

Comment: @JosephMansfield Well, I replaced `*ptr++` with `ptr++` and I got the same results. So I guess, both '*ptr++` and 'ptr++` modifies the value of `ptr`

Comment: @StianV.Svedenborg I tried `ptr++` and I got the same results.

Comment: @ParthibBiswas Well yes, it's the `++` that modifies the pointer. Just like `i++` modifies `i`. As Stian said, the `*` is dereferencing the pointer, which in this case is pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first program, you modified `ptr`, then in the third loop added values to its address, without resetting to the beginning of the array.

The second loop modifies the value of `ptr`:

```
for ( i=0 ; i<5 ; i++ )
{
    cout << *ptr ;
    *ptr++ ;
}
```

Then in the fourth loop you add values to its address without resetting it back to the beginning of the array.

```
cout << "ptr:" << endl;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    cout << (ptr+i) << endl;
}
```

With each iteration, you add only one, but the value comes out four larger each time, because a unit increment is the size of an `int`.

Comment: OK. This question might be little stupid but is there any 1 byte version of `int`?

Comment: There's a minimum size of two bytes for an int, according to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/size-of-int-long-etc . You can, however, represent an integral value with a 1-byte char.

Answer (score 2):

In first program `ptr` is modifying itself.
Note that `*ptr++;` is equivalent to `*(ptr++);` which altimately equivalent to

```
*ptr;
ptr++;
```

Adding `i` to `ptr` in the last `for` loop makes `ptr` to point somewhere else, unallocated memory location, instead of elements of `a`. That's why you are getting different address than that of address of array elements in your first program.

Answer (score 1):

After this loop

```
   for ( i=0 ; i<5 ; i++ )
    {
        cout << *ptr ;
        *ptr++ ;
    }
```

in the first program ptr points beyond the last element of the array because inside the loop ptr was increased. That to get the same result as in the second program you have to reset the pointer to point to the first element of the array after this loop

```
   for ( i=0 ; i<5 ; i++ )
    {
        cout << *ptr ;
        *ptr++ ;
    }

   ptr = a;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first program you are updating the pointer (changing the address the pointer is holding). Hence , after the loop, pointer is pointing beyond the last address of the array

```
        *ptr++ ;
```

In the second program you are not updating the address contained in the pointer.

```
*(ptr+i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just to clarify one thing.

There is nothing wrong with incrementing a pointer as supposed to adding to it. Incrementing pointers is the same concept as that behind iterators and is widely used in existing code.